# Time-taking task that has progress updates and inputs required in between - ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, signalr

I have run into a complex situation and I need your help!

Steps:

User uploads file(s) and clicks convert button.. then,

1. I have a time-taking file conversion process [coming up with the API].
2. I need to show the progress of the conversion.
3. I need to get few more inputs from the user in between the process.

Could you please give me an outline on how I could approach this situation?

Comment: Do you have any pre-existing code? Basically that is your outline is it not?

Comment: Thanks @Brandon for the question. Honestly, I couldn't find an approach to get started with the code.

Comment: With SignalR you can send progress messages to the clients. Here is an example: https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR-Client-Cpp/blob/dev/test/signalrclient-testhost/Connections/HubConnection.cs#L72-L82

Comment: Thank you for the example @Pawel